# GRPC Java load-balancing - start method is not being called from NameResolver

Tags: load-balancing, grpc, consul, grpc-java, spring-cloud-consul

We are trying to implement gRPC load balancing in Java with Consul Service Discovery.
Version info: grpc-java v1.30.0

The problem is that when the app runs, the start method from our custom NameResolver class not being called !

Here is our code:

Here is the custom NameResolver class (start method here is not being called)

I have put breakpoint at start method to check and it's not being called !

```
package com.bht.saigonparking.common.loadbalance;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;

import com.bht.saigonparking.common.util.LoggingUtil;

import io.grpc.Attributes;
import io.grpc.EquivalentAddressGroup;
import io.grpc.NameResolver;
import lombok.Getter;

/**
 *
 * @author bht
 */
@Getter
public final class SaigonParkingNameResolver extends NameResolver {

    private final URI consulURI;
    private final String serviceId;
    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    private Listener listener;
    private List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances;

    public SaigonParkingNameResolver(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient,
                                     URI consulURI,
                                     String serviceId,
                                     int pauseInSeconds) {

        this.consulURI = consulURI;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;

        /* run connection check timer */
        ConnectionCheckTimer connectionCheckTimer = new ConnectionCheckTimer(this, pauseInSeconds);
        connectionCheckTimer.runTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public String getServiceAuthority() {
        return consulURI.getAuthority();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Listener2 listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        loadServiceInstances();
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        // implement shutdown...
    }

    void loadServiceInstances() {

        List<EquivalentAddressGroup> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        serviceInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId);

        if (serviceInstances == null || serviceInstances.isEmpty()) {
            LoggingUtil.log(Level.WARN, "loadServiceInstances", "Warning",
                    String.format("no serviceInstances of %s", serviceId));
            return;
        }

        serviceInstances.forEach(serviceInstance -> {
            String host = serviceInstance.getHost();
            int port = serviceInstance.getPort();

            LoggingUtil.log(Level.INFO, "loadServiceInstances", serviceId, String.format("%s:%d", host, port));

            List<SocketAddress> socketAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
            socketAddressList.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
            addressList.add(new EquivalentAddressGroup(socketAddressList));
        });

        if (!addressList.isEmpty()) {
            listener.onAddresses(addressList, Attributes.EMPTY);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the custom NameResolverProvider class

```
package com.bht.saigonparking.common.loadbalance;

import java.net.URI;

import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;

import io.grpc.NameResolver;
import io.grpc.NameResolverProvider;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

/**
 * @author bht
 */
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class SaigonParkingNameResolverProvider extends NameResolverProvider {

    private final String serviceId;
    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    private final int pauseInSeconds;

    @Override
    protected boolean isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int priority() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return "consul";
    }

    @Override
    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI targetUri, NameResolver.Args args) {
        return new SaigonParkingNameResolver(discoveryClient, targetUri, serviceId, pauseInSeconds);
    }
}
```

Here is a class from Client

```
package com.bht.saigonparking.service.auth.configuration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.bht.saigonparking.api.grpc.user.UserServiceGrpc;
import com.bht.saigonparking.common.interceptor.SaigonParkingClientInterceptor;
import com.bht.saigonparking.common.loadbalance.SaigonParkingNameResolverProvider;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

/**
 *
 * @author bht
 */
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public final class ChannelConfiguration {

    private final SaigonParkingClientInterceptor clientInterceptor;

    @Bean("userResolver")
    public SaigonParkingNameResolverProvider userServiceNameResolverProvider(@Value("${connection.user-service.id}") String serviceId,
                                                                             @Value("${connection.refresh-period-in-seconds}") int refreshPeriod,
                                                                             @Autowired DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        return new SaigonParkingNameResolverProvider(serviceId, discoveryClient, refreshPeriod);
    }


    /**
     *
     * channel is the abstraction to connect to a service endpoint
     *
     * note for gRPC service stub:
     *      .newStub(channel)          --> nonblocking/asynchronous stub
     *      .newBlockingStub(channel)  --> blocking/synchronous stub
     */
    @Bean
    public ManagedChannel managedChannel(@Value("${spring.cloud.consul.host}") String host,
                                         @Value("${spring.cloud.consul.port}") int port,
                                         @Value("${connection.idle-timeout}") int timeout,
                                         @Value("${connection.max-inbound-message-size}") int maxInBoundMessageSize,
                                         @Value("${connection.max-inbound-metadata-size}") int maxInBoundMetadataSize,
                                         @Value("${connection.load-balancing-policy}") String loadBalancingPolicy,
                                         @Qualifier("userResolver") SaigonParkingNameResolverProvider nameResolverProvider) {
        return ManagedChannelBuilder
                .forTarget("consul://" + host + ":" + port)                     // build channel to server with server's address
                .keepAliveWithoutCalls(false)                                   // Close channel when client has already received response
                .idleTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)                    // 10000 milliseconds / 1000 = 10 seconds --> request time-out
                .maxInboundMetadataSize(maxInBoundMetadataSize * 1024 * 1024)   // 2KB * 1024 = 2MB --> max message header size
                .maxInboundMessageSize(maxInBoundMessageSize * 1024 * 1024)     // 10KB * 1024 = 10MB --> max message size to transfer together
                .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)                // set load balancing policy for channel
                .nameResolverFactory(nameResolverProvider)                      // using Consul service discovery for DNS querying
                .intercept(clientInterceptor)                                   // add internal credential authentication
                .usePlaintext()                                                 // use plain-text to communicate internally
                .build();                                                       // Build channel to communicate over gRPC
    }


    /* asynchronous user service stub */
    @Bean
    public UserServiceGrpc.UserServiceStub userServiceStub(@Autowired ManagedChannel channel) {
        return UserServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);
    }


    /* synchronous user service stub */
    @Bean
    public UserServiceGrpc.UserServiceBlockingStub userServiceBlockingStub(@Autowired ManagedChannel channel) {
        return UserServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong on our code ? 
We are looking forward to hearing from you soon !

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter. It automatically handles consul integration part for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

We thought that start will be called as the channel created. It's wrong !

Sorry as we misunderstood about gRPC load-balancing.

It's now called start on new service call !

Thanks !
Saigon Parking team.